# Magento: Custom email template with PDF attachment

Tags: magento, email, pdf

I have implemented "full product lising" page with all the products in all categories (With approximately 200 products, varies on adding new products). This is in a tabular format which has only two columns:

1. Project Name
2. Price

And I have implemented dynamic generation of pdf with all these 200 products.

Now my requirement is to send this pdf in an email to the specified email address. How can i do with magento? Do i need to create new email template with pdf attachment?

Please suggest a best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new email template under location

1) **app\locale\en_US\template\email\foldername/filename.html**

2) Add your configuration section in your modules config.xml. For ex:

```
<template>
            <email>
                <template_name module="NameSpace_ModuleName">
                    <label>Your Own Label</label>
                    <file>modulefolder/template_name.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </template_name>
            </email>
        </template>
```

3) Next, below is the code to add attachment to transactional email:

```
function GetTransactionalSender() {
    return array(
        'name'  => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/name'),
        'email' => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/email')
    );
}


function SendTransactionalEmail($templateId, $recepientEmail, $recepientName, $vars, $storeId, $pdf_attachment = '') {
    $status = false;
    try {
        $transactionalEmail = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
            ->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId));

            if (!empty($pdf_attachment) && file_exists($pdf_attachment)) {
                $transactionalEmail
                ->getMail()
                ->createAttachment(
                    file_get_contents($pdf_attachment),
                    Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                    Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                    Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                    basename($pdf_attachment)
            );
        }


        $transactionalEmail
            ->sendTransactional($templateId, GetTransactionalSender(), $recepientEmail, $recepientName, $vars);
        $status = true;
    } catch (Exception $e) { }
    return $status;
}

$template_id = 1;
$to_email = 'user@domain.com';
$to_name = 'User Name';
$vars = array();
$store_id = 1
$pdf_file = '/full/path/to/my/file.pdf';
$sent = SendTransactionalEmail($template_id, $to_email, $to_name, $vars, $store_id, $pdf_file);
```

Comment: Where is GetTransactionalSender() function that you have used in SendTransactionalEmail()